# How can I enable/disable a function depending on the size of an array?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

I'm still rather new to TMP so forgive me if this is a poorly worded question.

I'm trying to make a very generic mathematical Vector class to store any number of components, but defaults to 3 and using float as it's base representation. So if you default construct one of these vectors it will hold `(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)`

The values themselves are stored in a `std::array` and I would like to create accessor function for ease of use. I currently have this:

```
std::array<Type,SIZE> e;
Type x() const {return e.at(0);};
Type y() const {return e.at(1);};
Type z() const {return e.at(2);};
```

What I am trying to do now is also have one for the 4th component, `w` but only enable it if the size of this array is >= 4. so something like this:

```
template<class Type, std::enable_if<.......>>
Type w() const {return e.at(3);};
```

This is just a vague idea of what I think it should look like. I'm aware `concept` exists, but I'm also struggling to write one for this situation.

Comment: the question is somewhat unclear. THe code you posted is part of a class? They are member functions? What is `Type` , where does `SIZE` come from?

Comment: `requires(SIZE >= 4)`?

Comment: btw consider to return `const Type&` and probably you will also want to add the non-const accessors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With concepts you can simply do

```
Type w() const requires (SIZE >= 4) {return e.at(3);};
```

Comment: How about for pre-concepts, like C++17?

Comment: `s/concepts/constraints/` as concept is the "(type) traits".

Answer (score 5):

Prior to C++20 concepts, you can do this:

```
template<typename Type = float, size_t SIZE = 3>
class Vector {
    std::array<Type, SIZE> e;
public:
    template<typename Dummy = void, std::enable_if_t<SIZE >= 3, Dummy>* = nullptr>
    Type x() const { return e[0]; };

    template<typename Dummy = void, std::enable_if_t<SIZE >= 3, Dummy>* = nullptr>
    Type y() const { return e[1]; };

    template<typename Dummy = void, std::enable_if_t<SIZE >= 3, Dummy>* = nullptr>
    Type z() const { return e[2]; };

    template<typename Dummy = void, std::enable_if_t<SIZE >= 4, Dummy>* = nullptr>
    Type w() const { return e[3]; };
};
```

```
Vector v1;
v1.x();
v1.y();
v1.z();
//v1.w(); // ERROR
    
Vector<int, 4> v2; 
v2.x();
v2.y();
v2.z();
v2.w(); // OK
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/J0T69pwl6d)

---

Alternatively, you can also do this, like @Jarod42 suggested:

```
template<typename Type = float, size_t SIZE = 3>
class Vector {
    std::array<Type, SIZE> e;
public:
    template<size_t N = SIZE, std::enable_if_t<N >= 3>* = nullptr>
    Type x() const { return e[0]; };

    template<size_t N = SIZE, std::enable_if_t<N >= 3>* = nullptr>
    Type y() const { return e[1]; };

    template<size_t N = SIZE, std::enable_if_t<N >= 3>* = nullptr>
    Type z() const { return e[2]; };

    template<size_t N = SIZE, std::enable_if_t<N >= 4>* = nullptr>
    Type w() const { return e[3]; };
};
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/pkhemp86GH)

However, that would allow the user to explicitly make `w()` accessible to read from an invalid index, eg:

```
Vector v1; // only has indexes 0..2
v1.w<5>(); // NO ERROR, but accesses index 3
```

Comment: Not sure that `std::enable_if_t<SIZE >= 4 /*false*/, Dummy>` usage is pedantically correct. I think it is ill formed NDR. Using `template <std::size_t N, std::enable_if_t<N >= 4, bool> = false>` would be ok though.

Comment: @Bob_ the `3`s on the `x()`/`y()` methods are intentional, please don't edit them.

Comment: @Jarod42 the code I showed is valid and works. Your suggestion would require the user to explicitly supply `N` on every call, ie `v1.x<0>();` rather than letting `N` be deduced. Maybe you are thinking of `template <std::size_t N = SIZE, std::enable_if_t<N >= 4, bool> = false>`? [That would work](https://onlinegdb.com/pkhemp86GH), but it also allows the user to explicitly make `w()` accessible so it can read from an illegal index, eg: `v1.w<5>();`

Comment: Yes, I forgot defaulting to `SIZE`, hijacking might be protected (more defensive `enable_if` would have same issue I suspect in your code, but variadic pack might be a prevention way). For your version, I think that [temp#res.general-6.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1) (*"The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated"*). I think the `Dummy` to make it template dependent just hide the issue to compilers.

Comment: I won't. May I ask why you don't want to allow [smaller](https://godbolt.org/z/h6fchx9za) `Vector`s? The OP wrote "any number of components", so I thought 2D ones could [qualify](https://godbolt.org/z/4jzW3MhsK).

Comment: @Bob_ the way the OP worded their post implies to me that they don't want the accessor methods available for sizes less than 3. But if that is not true, they are free to adjust the `enable_if` conditions accordingly.